# Создание статических и/или динамических библитек из кода C++ c templates

Tags: cdt, mingw, eclipse, c++

Использую MinGW32 + Eclipse CDT... столкнулся с проблемой, что при использовании templates, которые я интенсивно использую, невозможно создать библиотеки (как статические, так и динамические). В результате свои библиотеки шаблонных классов приходится включать в очередной проект в виде исходников. В результате много компиляции и размер откомпилированного кода.

Посоветуйте... что делать. Может я чего-то не знаю...

С уважением,
Александр Бычков

Answer (score 1):

Вообще-то экспортирование шаблонов существует. [Пруф](http://www.comeaucomputing.com/4.0/docs/userman/export.html). Другой вопрос, что в C++ нормально это не сделано, т.е. самый работоспособный путь распространения библиотеки с шаблонами - распространение ее в исходных кодах. Ну, и скорее всего поэтому комитет по языку убрал эту сомнительную возможность из стандарта. [`[2]`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B#Exported_templates)